# "on the hunt for" VS "in the hunt for"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. A company is **on** the hunt for best minds
> 2. A company is **in** the hunt for best minds

I have seen two different prepositions preceding "hunt", namely in and on. Which one should I choose when I want to say "A company is on the lookout for best minds"

Comment: But your second sentence replaces *hunt* with *lookout* . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford rewrote!

Answer (score 3):

You want "on the hunt". That idiom means something is [being searched for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20the%20hunt), while "in the hunt" means [a competitor is still in the running](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20hunt). Example 2 would be appropriate only if you were talking about multiple companies competing to recruit from a specific pool.